# Entry point was not found.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is split up into 2 project. 1 of the project is just an ASP.NET MVC project, the other one a class library where I put shared code. The class library is using RazorGenerator to compile my views.

In the MVC application I'm using EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider so I can access resource files added in the class lib. I'm also using oauth providers to login to the application.

When I'm trying to start my application I'm getting the following exception.

```
[EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
System.Web.WebPages.IVirtualPathFactory.Exists(String virtualPath) +0
System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Exists>b__0(IVirtualPathFactory factory) +15
System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +146
System.Web.WebPages.VirtualPathFactoryManager.Exists(String virtualPath) +72
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage(WebPageRenderingBase page, IVirtualPathFactory virtualPathFactory, String appDomainAppVirtualPath, String fileName, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +131
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage(WebPageRenderingBase page, String fileName, IEn umerable`1 supportedExtensions) +13 2
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +200
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +294
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +175
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9688704
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154241/entry-point-was-not-found-exception

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it.

Assuming the project references are all right...

- Comment out all the  `<dependentAssembly>...</dependentAssembly>` sections in the web.config.
- Right click on the project and go into "Manage Nuget Packages"
- Remove any installed library and re-add it back

... this will recreate all the `<dependentAssembly>...</dependentAssembly>` sections and you should be good to go.

If you project references are not right... then uninstall all mvc related libraries and re-install