# MVC 5 and Simple Injector on VS 2012 EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I have application in .NET Framework 4.5 and SimpleInjector. When my app was without SI its start without problems, but when I added SI I cannot run it.
This is my code in Global.asax:

```
public static Container Initialize()
{
    var container = new Container();
    RegisterComponents(container);
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    container.RegisterMvcAttributeFilterProvider();

#if DEBUG
    container.Verify();
#endif

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

    return container;
}

public static void RegisterComponents(Container container)
{
    //container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    //container.Register<IUserManager, UserManager>();
}
```

and

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
SIInitializer.Initialize();
```

And I get this error on  DependencyResolver.SetResolver: Cannot find entry point.
StackTrace:

```
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.CacheDependencyResolver..ctor(IDependencyResolver resolver)
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.InnerSetResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver)
System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(IDependencyResolver resolver)
DS.App_Start.SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize() w c:\programyInne\DiS\DiS\App_Start\SimpleInjectorInitializer.cs:wiersz 29
DiS.MvcApplication.Application_Start() w c:\programyInne\DiS\DiS\Global.asax.cs:wiersz 30
```

Comment: I tried nk this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154241/entry-point-was-not-found-exception

Comment: I update MVC from 5.0 to 5.2 and now it works fine. Thanks