# Entry point was not found exception in Asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I tried to run an asp.net mvc project that are connected to the tfs server. I didn't change anything. But suddenly I get this error:

"Entry point was not found"

```
[EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext requestContext) +122
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +33
    System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +10
    System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +9709656
    System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e) +82
    System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

I will appreciate any help ...

Answer (score 0):

You should check references to assemblies. This error says about inconsistencies.
[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154241/entry-point-was-not-found-exception)

Comment: what do you mean exactly "You should check references to assemblies"